# Regular Expression : No match found

Tags: java, regex

I just started learning about regular expressions. I am trying to get the attribute values within "mytag" tags and used the following code, but it is giving me No match found exception.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class dummy {

    public static void testRegEx()
    {
    //  String pattern_termName = "(?i)\\[.*\\]()\\[.*\\]";

        Pattern patternTag;
        Matcher matcherTag;

        String mypattern= "\\[mytag attr1=&quot;(.*?)&quot; attr2=&quot;(.*?)&quot; attr3=&quot;(.*?)&quot;](.+?)\\[/mytag]";

        String term="[mytag attr1=\"20258044753052856\" attr2=\"A security \" attr3=\"cvvc\" ]TagTitle[/mytag]";


        patternTag = Pattern.compile(mypattern);

        matcherTag = patternTag.matcher(term);

        System.out.println(matcherTag.group(1)+"*********"+matcherTag.group(2)+"$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        testRegEx();    
    }

}
```

I have used `\"` in place of `"` but it still shows me same exception.

Comment: mytag attr1=`\\`"20258044753052856\"            where have matched this `\\`

Comment: Why you used `&quot` in the pattern instead of `"` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have used \", but it shows me the same exception.

Comment: @vks I dint get you!

Comment: ive changed to String mypattern= "\\[mytag attr1=\\\"(.*?)\\\" attr2=\\\"(.*?)\\\" attr3=\\\"(.*?)\\\"](.+?)\\[/mytag]";  But its still not working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to check the matcher object against find function and also you need to use `\"`
 instead of `&quot;`,. The [find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

```
Pattern patternTag;
Matcher matcherTag;
String mypattern= "\\[mytag attr1=\"(.*?)\" attr2=\"(.*?)\" attr3=\"(.*?)\"\\s*](.+?)\\[/mytag]";
String term="[mytag attr1=\"20258044753052856\" attr2=\"A security \" attr3=\"cvvc\" ]TagTitle[/mytag]";
patternTag = Pattern.compile(mypattern);
matcherTag = patternTag.matcher(term);
while(matcherTag.find()){
       System.out.println(matcherTag.group(1)+"*********"+matcherTag.group(2)+"$$$$$$$$$$$$");
}
```

**Output:**

```
20258044753052856*********A security $$$$$$$$$$$$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nB2dV5/1)

Answer (score 0):

`\\s+` or `\\s*` missing

code:

```
final String  pattern = "\\[\\s*mytag\\s+attr1\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s+attr2\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s+attr3\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*\\](.+?)\\[/mytag\\]";
final String  input   = "[mytag attr1=\"20258044753052856\" attr2=\"A security \" attr3=\"cvvc\" ]TagTitle[/mytag]";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile( pattern );
final Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
if( m.matches()) {
   System.out.println(
      m.group(1) + '\t' + m.group(2) + '\t' + m.group(3) + '\t' + m.group(4));
}
```

outpout:

```
20258044753052856   A security  cvvc    TagTitle
```